# returning rows within range in pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
              count
year   person   
       a.smith  1
2008   b.johns  2
       c.gilles 3
       a.smith  4
2009   b.johns  3
       c.gilles 2
```

in which both `year` and `person` are part of the index. I'd like to return all rows with `a.smith` for all years. I can locate a count for a specific year with `df.loc[(2008, 'a.smith)]`, which outputs 1. But if I try `df.loc[(:,'a.smith`)], I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

How do I use `df.loc` for a range of index values in a MultiIndex?

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.IndexSlice`

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:,'a.smith'],:]
Out[200]: 
              count
year person        
2008 a.smith      1
2009 a.smith      4
```

Data Input

```
df
Out[211]: 
               count
year person         
2008 a.smith       1
     b.johns       2
     c.gilles      3
2009 a.smith       4
     b.johns       3
     c.gilles      2
```

Comment: I get `UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'`

Comment: @snapcrack I have attached the data I used